# Guess My Number Game

Tags: java

I am learning java and now making a game Guess My Number, where computer chooses a random number which is declared as int `rNumber` for random number. i have created 2 buttons, guess and exit, when player enters a number in texfield next to label and click on GUESS button then it displays the message which is mentioned by me in `GuessButtonHandler`. but here my GUESS button is not working.There is no error in my code i can see a `JFrame` but Guess Button is not working. can you please tell me my mistake? please help me. Many Thanks!

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
class GuessMyNumberGame extends JFrame
{
    public JLabel guessL, resultL;
    public JTextField guessTF, resultTF;
    public int rNumber = (int) (Math.random() * 100);

    public GuessMyNumberGame()
    {
        setTitle("Guess My Number");
        Container c = getContentPane();
        c.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,2));

        guessL = new JLabel("Guess a number between 1 & 100");
        resultL = new JLabel("Result");

        guessTF = new JTextField(15);
        resultTF = new JTextField(15);

        JButton GuessB = new JButton("Guess");
        GuessB.addActionListener(new GuessButtonHandler());

        JButton exitB = new JButton("Exit");
        exitB.addActionListener(new ExitButtonHandler());

        c.add(guessL);
        c.add(guessTF);
        c.add(resultL);
        c.add(resultTF);
        c.add(GuessB);
        c.add(exitB);

        setSize(500,900);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    }

    class GuessButtonHandler implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            int a = Integer.parseInt(guessTF.getText());
            do
            {
                if(a == rNumber)
                {
                    resultTF.setText("Good Job! your Guess is perfect" +a);
                }
                else if (a < rNumber)
                {
                    resultTF.setText("your guess is lower than the random number" +a);
                }
                else
                    resultTF.setText("your guess is higher than the random number" +a);
            }
            while( a != rNumber);
        }
    }

    class ExitButtonHandler implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        GuessMyNumberGame gmn = new GuessMyNumberGame();
    }
}
```

Comment: Just wanted to point out that this gives a number between 0 and 99, not 1 and 100 (`Math.random()` returns on range `[0,1)`)

Comment: Variable names should NOT start with an upper case character. "GuessB" is the only variable in your code that does start with an upper case character. Be consistent! There is no excuse for not following the standards!

Answer (score 3):

Remove the do-while loop in `GuessButtonHandler`, but keep the content. You are getting no input in that loop, so you will get an endless loop.